# Improvment for colored wheels in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\definecolor{forestgreen}{RGB}{34,139,34}
\definecolor{limegreen}{RGB}{0,255,0}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
%%  \clip (5,-4) rectangle (-1,1);
%%  \fill[left color=red,right color=magenta] (-1,1) -- (5,-4) -- (5,1) -- cycle;
%       \foreach \x in {0,30,...,350}
%       {
%           \fill[green] (0,0) -- (\x-10:1) arc(\x-10:\x+10:1) -- (\x+10:1) -- cycle;
%       }
        \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
            \foreach \x in {0,30,...,350}
        {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{(1/5)*\x}
            \fill[green!\a!yellow] (0,0) -- (\x-10:1) arc(\x-10:\x+10:1) -- (\x+10:1) -- cycle;
        }
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
            \fill[inner color=orange!30,outer color=orange!80] (0,0) circle(1);
                \foreach \x in {0,30,...,350}
            {
                \fill[inner color=red!80,outer color=red] (0,0) -- (\x-10:1) arc(\x-10:\x+10:1) -- (\x+10:1) -- cycle;
            }
            \begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm]
                \foreach \x in {0,30,...,350}
            {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{(1/5)*\x}
                \fill[red!\a!blue] (0,0) -- (\x-10:1) arc(\x-10:\x+10:1) -- (\x+10:1) -- cycle;
            }
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=1.75cm,yshift=-1.5cm]
            \foreach \x in {0,30,...,350}
            {
                \fill[orange] (0,0) -- (\x-10:1) arc(\x-10:\x+10:1) -- (\x+10:1) -- cycle;
                \fill[left color=blue!80,right color=blue!40] (0,0) -- (\x-10:.6) arc(\x-10:\x+10:1) -- (\x+10:.5) -- cycle;
            }
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3.5cm]
            \fill[inner color=blue!30,outer color=blue!80] (0,0) circle(1);
            \foreach \x in {0,30,...,350}
            {
                \fill[inner color=yellow!80,outer color=yellow] (0,0) -- (\x-10:1) arc(\x-10:\x+10:1) -- (\x+10:1) -- cycle;
            }
        \end{scope}
        \fill[left color=red,right color=magenta] (3,-5.5) circle(1);
        \fill[left color=limegreen,right color=forestgreen] (.5,-5.5) circle(1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: How can be the code cleaned up (e.g. using `saveboxes`)?

Comment: +1 I do not see a need for `\savebox`es here. You are not nesting `tikzpicture`s nor do you use the same thing over and over. However, if you want to make these things more "funky", consider using a `color wheel`. ;-) Another way of marginally improving the code is to use the `evaluate` syntax in ` \foreach \x in {0,30,...,350}
        {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{(1/5)*\x}` : ` \foreach \x [evalutate=\x as \a using {\x/5}] in {0,30,...,350}
        {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{(1/5)*\x}`

Comment: On pag. 644 of pgfmanual there is an impressive example of a wheel like yours.